# Is using GET in my query_posts statement bad? (WP)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$category = $_GET['sortBy'];
query_posts(array('order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $category));
```

Is this a security risk?
Should i sanitize get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress, this is not necessary. But always keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should always sanitize data that comes from an untrusted source; since $_POST and $_GET (and $_COOKIE) data can be edited easily by the user to contain malicious code/garbage values, you should always validate their contents.

Generally, I would suggest calling `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, or using prepared statements at a bare minimum.  However, it seems you are using WordPress, so you will want to look at the WordPress documentation to see how (and if) they sanitize the parameters passed to their `query_posts()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should sanitize all `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` variables. You can make use of many different functions, one of them being `mysql_real_escape_string()`. You can read a lot about it on the internet. An article that might be useful for you is [this](http://www.bitrepository.com/sanitize-data-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html) one.

Other than that I'd always advise you to make use of `$_POST` variables because they are not visible to the user upon submitting a form. While `$_GET` variables are shown in the address bar (e.g.:  http://www.website.com/submit.php?name=John&surname=Doe&activationkey=81sd6s1). This makes it **very** easy to modify for a user with bad intentions. While editing `$_POST` variables require a little more skills.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress santize it automatically, you do not need to worry about it here. However, in these cases, use

```
mysql_real_escape_string();
mysqli_real_escape_string();
```